# Vuejs error 401 Unauthorized from DRF api

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

Vue Js error (401 Unauthorized)

[Vue Js Error: 401 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VDFm.png)

Software Used-

DRF
Vuejs

while calling DRF api in Vue js (using axios) unbale to get data.

below code in App.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'Header': Header,
    'Footer': Footer,
    'Navbar': Navbar
  },
  data () {
    return {
      info: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    var self = this
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/management/api/list/')
      .then(function (res) {
        self.info = res.data
        console.log('Data: ', res.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of the code. Instead add in some code and indent them with 4 (four) spaces.

Comment: sure will take care next time

Comment: You can edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting to an API which is protected and need authorization credentials to be available.

If you are using DRF token-management systems, you should first get a token from proper API endpoint. then pass this token via `Authorization` header in request.
For example if you are using jwt token management system in django, then you should send requests like this:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/management/api/list/',  { Authorization: `jwt ${token}`})
  .then(function (res) {
    self.info = res.data
    console.log('Data: ', res.data)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error)
  })
```

Remember it really depends on your Authentication backend you are using. So if you can give more details about how you implemented your django DRF APIs, I guess we all can help you much better.

Comment: update your post and add `REST_FRAMEWORK` in your settings.py file.

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
    (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.URLPathVersioning',
}

Comment: you have jwt enabled. so there should be no problem by the method that i suggest. did you get token from API?

Comment: How I can check about jwt token ?

Comment: do you have any API to get jwt token from server? register this in your urls.py `url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),` also [read this](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)